# what happens if php.ini is missing?

Tags: php

What happens if php.ini is missing?  Does PHP load with a default configuration?  In phpinfo(), it says the configuration file path is /etc, however it also says Loaded Configuration File (none).  I went into /etc, and noticed there is no php.ini, only php.ini.default.  PHP is working though, so I'm guessing it must load with default settings.  Can anybody confirm this for me?

Comment: I did `php --ini` which also told me that there was no config file, but it DID tell me the directory was `/etc`.  So I did a `sudo nano /etc/php.ini` and added a comment (starting with a `;`) and did `php --ini` again - and it showed the file was present!  Just to be sure, I added some illegal characters, and went back to `php --ini` which told me there was a parse error.  So it appears you can always add a php.ini file - even if it starts out blank.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP has what amounts to a php.ini compiled into it. The php.ini file on the system is there merely to override those pre-compiled defaults. If there's no php.ini, the compile-time values are in charge.

Answer (score 5):

It does load default settings, yes.

Comment: And if you want to see these default settings.. phpinfo() function in a PHP file will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

if php.ini is missing , u can choose one of this files and rename it to php.ini => this will give u the same results

**php.ini-development
php.ini-production**

I wish this can help ;)