# Lion Upgrade and php.ini is invisible

Tags: php, macos, osx-lion

I upgrade to Mac OS Lion. My simple php code which was working earlier still continues to work. But when I access /etc folder in Finder, I do not see my php.ini file. It does show me a php.ini.default file with a modified date the same as when I upgrade to Mac OS Lion.

I did check on the terminal with the following command: **php --ini**. And I got the following response: **Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc**. This tells me that the file is in the /etc folder. Am I missing something here? I also tried to list the files in /etc on the terminal and it does not show php.ini file in the list.

The reason I want to access php.ini is to set it up to use PDO to access mysql database running locally.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There was a similar question which was answered correctly. Here is a link to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3962710/977224

Answer (score 2):

Invisible? More likely non-existent. Feel free to create one from `php.ini.default`.

Answer (score 0):

To show all hidden files you would launch a terminal window and type in the following commands

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

To rehide the hidden files you would use

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
killall Finder
```

The reason you call "killall Finder" is to restart the finder so the changes take affect

Comment: by default the php.ini should not be hidden. It is possible that it was deleted.

Comment: the php.ini by default does not exist. Here is the link to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3962710/977224